# Remove imported class from object Java

Tags: java

I need to create a `toString` method which prints out the coordinates of a certain person in a building, like so:

```
private void toString() {
    if (level == destination)
        System.out.println(name + id + " on level " + level);
    else
        System.out.println(name + "(" + id + ")" + " on level " + level + " waiting to go to level " + destination);
```

Unfortunately, `java.util.*` imports a `toString` class when used also. It is important that *"toString"* is the name of the class invoked by the program, or I will not receive marks for this module. Could anyone please help?

See below for the entire object:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int level;
    private int destination;
    private boolean aboard;

    public Person (int id, String name, int level){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.destination = level;
    }

    private void toString(){
        if(level == destination)
        System.out.println(name + id + " on level " + level);

        else
        System.out.println(name + "(" + id + ")" + " on level " + level + " waiting to go to level " + destination);
    }
}
```

(Note this is only a small part of the overall project).

Comment: Every class will invoke it's own `toString()` method if you overrode it; otherwise it will fall back to the superclass's toString, which is in this case `Object` - printing out it's class instance reference. In other words, this should be OK - i don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Scratch that, i know what you did wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can override `toString()` to return void.

Comment: you also can´t lower the visibility of the inherited methods, so leave it `public`.

Comment: a) `toString` is not a class, but a method b) the import does absolutely nothing in this case; you're extending `java.lang.Object` containing a `toString` method and you cannot change the fact that your class needs to extend `Object` or a class extending `Object`; The `java.lang` package is imported by default BTW.

Comment: You may want to learn about the terms `Class`, `Method`, `Inheritance` and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, in order for your class instance to implicitly invoke it's own `toString()` method, it should look like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    if(level == destination)
    return name + id + " on level " + level;

    else
    return name + "(" + id + ")" + " on level " + level + " waiting to go to level " + destination;
}
```

insteasd of invoking System.out.println.

TL;DR - you're not overriding `toString()` because you changed the method signature from `public String toString()` to `private void toString()`.

Comment: Technically he can still invoke System.out.println in the toString method (he shouldn't). It is a school assignment, it can be weird like that.

Comment: @MatheM following that logic, his `toString()` was perfectly fine from the start, rigth? except that it wasn't as it wasn't returning a string. Double printing would've been a different issue though.

Comment: It wasn't right and it won't compile but his teacher might actually want him to print text from inside toString method. It wouldn't be the craziest thing teachers want students to do.

Comment: Then the teacher deserves a downvote for asking him to implement a `toString()` that prints to stdout instead of strigifying the object... :/ so if you're in the same class with him (since you know what his teacher wants / *might have wanted*) feel free to tell him that.

Answer (score 2):

Your toString method should be public and it would be perfect if it had @Override annotation:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    //...
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(level == destination)
            return name + id + " on level " + level;

        return name + "(" + id + ")" + " on level " + level + " waiting to go to level " + destination;           
    }
}
```

Let's introduce you to the topic. In Java we have classes which have fields and methods. In your case `Person` is a class, it has 5 `fields` and two methods. One of them is a constructor. Of course you might have more, but it's what you have shown us.

Access modifiers are used to restrict not wanted access. Method `toString()` must be public because it's declared so in the parent class. `private` methods can be only called from the inside of a class so from other methods. Same with fields.

You can't import methods from `java.util`. You import classes. Each class extends `Object` in Java and `Object` has methods `public String toString()`. If you won't override it, `your_class.toString()` will invoke the default, `Object.toString()` method.

`public String toString(){//somecode}` means:

the method is public, it returns String and it's name is toString. If you want to print the `toString()` value use:

`System.out.println(myPerson.toString());`

Comment: *"Method toString() must be public as you almost always call it from the outside of class."*  -- Wrong. It has to be `public` because it is inherited from `Object`s `public String toString()` and *visibilty cannot be reduced* by derived classes.

Comment: Thank you for the walk through of all your points. I'm new to programming and appreciate the time you took to step through everything.

Comment: @Neuw if this answer was helpful, simply mark it by clicking the gray tick below the score.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you spend some time reading on *visibility* aspects of Java.

Most likely, your teachers don't expect you to implement a *private* version of toString() - they want you to override the public version that each and any class in Java inherits from java.lang.Object.

```
class Whatever {
   @Override
   public String toString() { 
     return whatever;
   }
}
```

And please note: each keyword there has its meaning - you really want to study what @Override is about; and what the difference between private and public is; and of course: toString() methods are supposed to return a string object, they aren't void!

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct that Objects in java inherit the `.toString()` method (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29))

The way to override the standard `.toString()` method from the object is with the Override-Annotation, like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    // Do something here
}
```

So currently your code could work, however your `.toString()` method doesn't override the standard method because of the different return type (void VS String). As long as the return types are different Java doesn't recognize them as the same method.

So changing the return type and adding the `@Override` annotation should fix your issue!

Comment: You cannot use any visibility but `public` with a overridden `toString()` method.

Comment: This won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

Well this may not answer your question directly but so long as your program is like that, it won't compile. The reason is that you are not allowed to override any `java` method with weaker privileges.
The `toString` method was declared `public` on the ***grandfather at the top*** `java.lang.Object`. All java classes automatically inherit it so there is nothing you can do about it except overriding. Now, this method is automatically called whenever you call a print method on an object like this:

```
System.out.print( MyClass );
```

What you are expected to do is not to create a new `toString()` method but to override the existing one. To override a `toString()` method, you must write thus:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String message = "Whatever";
    return String.format("What to print.%s", message);
}
```